# F#: grouping by recurring sequences of elements

Tags: f#, seq

I have a sequence of pairs (key, value) like

```
[("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("a", 111), ("b", 3), ("bb", 1), ("bb", -1), ...]
```

, what is the most effective way to convert it into sequence like

```
[("a", [1,2,111]), ("b", [3]), ("bb", [1,-1])]
```

or similar?

The sequence has following property: it's really big (>2Gb)

This makes Seq.groupBy really ineffective and incorrect, are there any other ways to do it?

P.S.: this sequence:

```
[("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("a", 111), ("bb", 1), ("bb", -1), ("a", 5), ("a", 6), ...]
```

should be converted as

```
[("a", [1,2,111]), ("bb", [1,-1]), ("a", [5,6]), ...]
```

--

edit #1: Fixed incorrect sample

edit #2: Sequence is big, so lazy (or fastest) solution is preferred

Comment: how is seq.groupby wrong?

Comment: @JohnPalmer: groupBy uses a [dictionary internally](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/37a100b7caafde0f4df5a1924c9f65f4a18277a8/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1458), and I guess this is what the OP wants to avoid. He seems to be after a behaviour similar to `uniq` where only adjacent duplicates count.

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer - there are a whole bunch of reasons why groupby might be incorrect - I was trying to get OP to say what applied to his situation -

Comment: @JohnPalmer groupBy is incorrect in this case, because for [("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("a", 111), ("bb", 1), ("bb", -1), ("a", 5), ("a", 6), ...] it will return [("a", [1,2,111, 5, 6]), ("bb", [1,-1]),  ...] instead of [("a", [1,2,111]), ("bb", [1,-1]), ("a", [5,6]), ...]

Comment: @MarkSeemann This question isn't  really a duplicate as it requires laziness. Also, we can generate a lazy sequence with eager chunks. Wrap the input sequence with `Some`, slap on a `None`; feed to `Seq.scan` with the previous key and an accumulator as state. Finally to `Seq.choose` to strip the state.

Comment: @kaefer OK, reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the option to get lazy results, then I don't think there's an elegant way without maintaining mutable state. Here's a relatively straight-forward one with mutation. You maintain a store of the last key you saw, and all the values that correspond to that:

```
let s = [("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 111); ("bb", 1); ("bb", -1); ("a", 5); ("a", 6)]
let s2 = 
    [
        let mutable prevKey = None
        let mutable values = System.Collections.Generic.List<_>()
        let init key value = 
            prevKey <- Some key
            values.Clear()
            values.Add value
        for (key, value) in s do
            match prevKey with
            | None -> init key value
            | Some k when k = key -> values.Add value
            | Some k -> 
                yield (k, List.ofSeq values)
                init key value
        match prevKey with
        | Some k -> yield (k, List.ofSeq values)
        | _ -> ()
    ]
```

This gives:

```
val s2 : (string * int list) list =
  [("a", [1; 2; 111]); ("bb", [1; -1]); ("a", [5; 6])]
```

For lazy evaluation, replace the `[ ... ]` with `seq { ... }`

Comment: The problem with this kind of solution that it isn't lazy-evaluated -- it will continue to read sequence till it's final element; also either your version, or my similar solution are *slower* then Seq.groupBy (which ofc gives incorrect answer, but...)

Comment: Also this version has a mistake, the correct result should be:
[("a", [1; 2; 111]); ("bb", [1; -1]); ("a", [5; 6])]

Comment: Bug fixed. if you want lazy, just replace the enclosing `[ ... ]` with `seq { ... }`

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer your code has a bug and returns   `[("a", [1; 2; 111]); ("a", [1]); ("a", [-1; 5; 6])]` for me. I suggested an edit

Comment: @Ringil: thanks, goes to show that shuffling code around in a text editor can have unintended consequences...

Answer (score 3):

A simple recursive approach with no mutable state.

```
let rec chunk inseq (accumelem,accumlist) = 
    match inseq with
    |(a,b)::c -> 
        match accumelem with
        |Some(t) -> if t=a then chunk c (accumelem,b::accumlist) else (t,accumlist)::(chunk c (Some(a),b::[]))
        |None -> chunk c (Some a,b::[])
    |[] ->         
        match accumelem with
        |Some(t) -> (t,accumlist)::[]
        |None -> []


chunk [("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 111); ("bb", 1); ("bb", -1); ("a", 5);("a", 6)] (None,[])

val it : (string * int list) list =
     [("a", [111; 2; 1]); ("bb", [-1; 1]); ("a", [6; 5])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
let test = [("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 111); ("bb", 1); ("bb", -1); ("a", 5); ("a", 6)]

let groupByAdjacentElements alist = 
    let rec group a groupAcc prevElement adjacentAcc =
        match a with
        | [] -> match adjacentAcc with
                | [] -> groupAcc
                | _ -> (prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc)::groupAcc
        | (b, c)::tail -> if b = prevElement then
                             group tail groupAcc prevElement (c::adjacentAcc)
                          else
                             group tail ((prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc)::groupAcc) b [c]

    group alist [] (fst alist.Head) []
    |> List.rev

let b = groupByAdjacentElements test
```

It returns:   `[("a", [1; 2; 111]); ("bb", [1; -1]); ("a", [5; 6])]`

If you want lazy evaluation, you should consider trying [LazyList](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-lazylist-1.html)

EDIT: Here's a script comparing LazyList from [ExtCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtCore/) to the accepted solution. It generates a large text file and then does the transformations asked for. Note that the LazyList is returned in reverse order:

```
open System.Diagnostics
open System.IO
open ExtCore

let fileName = "Test.txt"
let outFile = new StreamWriter(fileName)
for i in [1..20000*300] do
    outFile.WriteLine("a,1")
    outFile.WriteLine("a,2")
    outFile.WriteLine("a,111")
    outFile.WriteLine("bb,1")
    outFile.WriteLine("bb,-1")
    outFile.WriteLine("a,5")
    outFile.WriteLine("a,6")
    outFile.WriteLine("c,8")
outFile.Close()

printfn "Finished Writing to File"

let data = System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName) 
            |> Seq.map (fun i -> let parts = i.Split(',')
                                 (parts.[0], parts.[1]))
printfn "Finished Reading File"

let s2 data = 
    [
        let mutable prevKey = None
        let mutable values = System.Collections.Generic.List<_>()
        let init key value = 
            prevKey <- Some key
            values.Clear()
            values.Add value
        for (key, value) in data do
            match prevKey with
            | None -> init key value
            | Some k when k = key -> values.Add value
            | Some k -> 
                yield (k, List.ofSeq values)
                init key value
        match prevKey with
        | Some key -> yield (key, List.ofSeq values)
        | _ -> ()
    ]

let groupByAdjacentElements aseq = 
    let alist = LazyList.ofSeq aseq
    let rec group alist groupAcc prevElement adjacentAcc =
        match alist with
        | Cons((b, c), tail) -> 
            if b = prevElement then
                group tail groupAcc prevElement (c::adjacentAcc)
            else
                group tail (LazyList.consDelayed (prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc) (fun () -> groupAcc)) b [c]
        | Nil -> 
            match adjacentAcc with
            | [] -> groupAcc
            | _ -> LazyList.consDelayed (prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc) (fun () -> groupAcc)


    group alist LazyList.empty (fst (alist.Head())) []

let groupByAdjacentElementsList aseq = 
    let alist = aseq |> Seq.toList
    let rec group a groupAcc prevElement adjacentAcc =
        match a with
        | [] -> match adjacentAcc with
                | [] -> groupAcc
                | _ -> (prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc)::groupAcc
        | (b, c)::tail -> if b = prevElement then
                             group tail groupAcc prevElement (c::adjacentAcc)
                          else
                             group tail ((prevElement, List.rev adjacentAcc)::groupAcc) b [c]

    group alist [] (fst alist.Head) []
    |> List.rev

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let stopwatch = new Stopwatch()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let b = s2 data
    printfn "The result is: %A" b
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "It took %A ms." stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    System.GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() |> ignore
    stopwatch.Reset()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let b = groupByAdjacentElements data
    printfn "The result is: %A" b
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "It took %A ms." stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    System.GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() |> ignore
    stopwatch.Reset()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let b = groupByAdjacentElementsList data
    printfn "The result is: %A" b
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "It took %A ms." stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    0
```

I when using files of around 300MB in size, `LazyList` was slightly slower (83s to 94s) than the `seq` solution. That said LazyList has the major advantage that iterating over it is cached, unlike the sequence solution. The normal list solution was faster than both even when doing List.rev (without it was around 73s).

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by adjacent keys can be also done without mutable bindings. With `Seq.scan`, it's possible to generate a lazy sequence with eager chunk. It already provides for one of the special cases, the first element of the sequence; by wrapping the input sequence as options followed by `None` we can take care of the other. Afterwards, we skip over intermediate results and strip out the state with `Seq.choose`.

For maximum versatility, I'd like to suggest a signature similar to `Seq.groupBy`,

> ```
> f:('T -> 'Key) -> xs:seq<'T> -> seq<'Key * 'T list> when 'Key : equality
> ```

which takes a key projection function as first argument.

```
let chunkBy (f : 'T-> 'Key) xs =
    // Determine key and wrap in option
    seq{for x in xs -> Some(f x, x)
        // Indicates end of sequence
        yield None }
    |> Seq.scan (fun (_, acc, previous) current ->
        match previous, current with
        | Some(pKey, _), Some(key, value) when pKey = key ->
            // No intermediate result, but add to accumulator
            None, value::acc, current
        | _ ->
            // New state is 3-tuple of previous key and completed chunk,
            // accumulator from current element, and new previous element
            Option.map (fun (k, _) -> k, List.rev acc) previous,
            Option.map snd current |> Option.toList, current )
        (None, [], None)
    |> Seq.choose (fun (result, _, _) -> result)
```

This can be adopted to OP's requirements by providing also a result projection function.

```
let chunkBy2 (f : 'T-> 'Key) (g : 'T->'Result)  =
    chunkBy f >> Seq.map (fun (k, gs) -> k, List.map g gs)
// val chunkBy2 :
//   f:('T -> 'Key) -> g:('T -> 'Result) -> (seq<'T> -> seq<'Key * 'Result list>)
//      when 'Key : equality

["a", 1; "a", 2; "a", 111; "b", 3; "bb", 1; "bb", -1]
|> chunkBy2 fst snd
// val it : seq<string * int list> =
//   seq [("a", [1; 2; 111]); ("b", [3]); ("bb", [1; -1])]

Seq.initInfinite (fun x ->
    if (x / 2) % 2 = 0 then "a", x else "b", x)
|> chunkBy2 fst snd
|> Seq.skip 50000
// val it : seq<string * int list> =
//   seq
//     [("a", [100000; 100001]); ("b", [100002; 100003]); ("a", [100004; 100005]);
//      ("b", [100006; 100007]); ...]
```